# Xpath: Get certain values

Tags: xpath

Take a xml-file like this:

```
<games>
    <game>
        <place>xxx</place>
        <date>2013-10-02</date>
    </game>
    <game>
        <place>yyy          </place>
        <date>2013-10-03</date>
    </game>
    <game>
        <place>zzz</place>
        <date>2013-10-03</date>
    </game>
    <game>
        <place>aaa</place>
        <date>2013-10-03</date>
        <status>1</status>
    </game>
    <game>
        <place>bbb</place>
        <date>2013-10-03</date>
        <status>9</status>
    </game>
</games>
```

Now, not only do I need to know, which "game" does have a tag named "status", but also what value do this tags have (in this example: 1 and 9 ).

> //game/status

only leeds me to all the nodes with a tag "status", but I can't figure out, how to fetch the specific tag, just to ask for the value.
Can anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: To be able to answer this in a meaningful way we need to know how you're using the XPath expression(s) - what programming language/toolkit/application etc.  It sounds like you're asking for a two-step process here, first find the `game` elements that have a `status` and then loop over them and extract the `status` value from each one.  This isn't something you can do in a single XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below expression will give you the result:

```
 /games/game[status]/status/text()
```

`/games/game[status]` will give you all the `game` node which has `status` node. Then `/games/game[status]/status` will you give you only the `status` nodes from the selected `game` node. Then finally top mentioned will help you to extract the text values within status node.

Comment: Thanks, 
`/games/game[status]/status/text()`
give me all I need.
@Ian Roberts: I'm using python for data-extracting and thought about a two-step process. But @Arup Rakshit 's answer makes it easier.